# Monotonicity of root of hyperbolic function

Tags: real-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

For $\kappa \geq \alpha>0$ and $y \geq 0$, consider the following equation:

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{\alpha }{\kappa }} \tanh \left(y \sqrt{1-\frac{\alpha }{\kappa }}\right)=\tanh \left(y-\frac{\alpha  }{2}\right)$$

I have proven that, for each $\alpha$, there is a unique $y$ satisfying this equation, call it $y^*(\alpha)$.

I want to show that $y^*(\alpha)$ is increasing in $\alpha$ if $\alpha\leq \kappa$.

Comment: Can you give some motivation for this question? What evidence do you have that it is true? Is it part of a broader research problem you are trying to solve? On its own it seems like a somewhat "standard" calculus problem

Comment: "I have proven that, for each $\alpha$, there is a unique $y$ satisfying this equation, call it $y^*(\alpha)$." -- Can you share that?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I apologize for the earlier comment. Here is the correct proof:

We first define constants $a$ and $b$ appropriately so that the equation above can be rewritten as

$f(y) \equiv b \tanh{b y} - \tanh{(y-a)} = 0.  $

We have $f(0) = - tanh(-a) > 0$, and $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} f(y)=b-1 < 0$, so a real root exists. 

To prove it is unique, consider the derivative $f'(y) = b^2 (1-\tanh^2{(by)}) - (1-\tanh^2{(y-a)}). $

At any $y$ that is a root we must then have: $$f'(y) = b^2(1-tanh^2{by}) - (1-b^2 tanh^2{by}) = b^2-1 < 0,$$

Which proves $y$ is unique.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I suggest you respond to [Max Horn;s comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452502/monotonicity-of-root-of-hyperbolic-function#comment1170263_452502) as well. Otherwise, your question may end up closed.